# How to redirect to another page after Knockout click event

Tags: knockout.js

Each page in a multi-page site displays a logout link and binds to a view model that implements authentication functionality and state. Here is a simplification:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: logout">Logout</a>
...
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.authenticated = ko.observable(true);                
    self.logout = function () {            
        self.authenticated(false);
    };
};
```

Upon logout, I want to redirect back to the site's login page. I know I can do it in the logout function:

```
self.logout = function () {
    self.authenticated(false);
    window.location.href = "login.html";
};
```

But to maintain a cleaner separation between view and view model, I would rather the view respond to change in the authenticated property of the view model. I envision something like this, though this example does not work - the script block is not hidden and consequently the redirect always occurs:

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: authenticated()"><script>alert("window.location.href = 'login.html';");</script></div>
```

So, how do we redirect here in an MVVM manner? I appreciate everyone's assistance; Knockout is a fantastic library.

Comment: Is there some reason the click event cant perform the redirect?

Comment: Hi @Tyrius - Interestingingly enough, this does nothing: '<a href="http://www.google.com" data-bind="click: logout">Logout</a>'

Answer (score 4):

The reason this wasn't redirecting to the login page:

```
<a href="login.html" data-bind="click: logout">Logout</a>
```

was because I wasn't returning true in the bound handler to continue the event chain:

```
self.logout = function () {        
    self.authenticated(false);
    return true;
};
```

Solved!